# continuity of a function and iterated integrals

Tags: continuity, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\times [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as : 
\begin{equation}
     \label{eq:aqui-le-mostramos-como-hacerle-la-llave-grande}
     f(x,y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
   1      & \mathrm{if\ } x ~is~rational    \\
   2y & \mathrm{if\ } x~is~irrational  
  \end{array}
      \right.
\end{equation}

I have to show that $f$ is continuous on $[1,0]\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ and also prove that the set of discontinuities of $f$ is:
\begin{equation}\notag
    \left([1,0]\times [0,\frac{1}{2})\right)\cup \left([0,1]\times(\frac{1}{2},1]\right)
\end{equation}

I have no idea how to start, also I would like to know if obtaining that result can help me to know if the iterated integrals of the function exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to math.stackexchange. Here's one approach using some topology. For showing continuity on $A:=[0,1]\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$, it suffices to show that $(f|_A)^{-1}(V)$ is open (relative to $A$) for any open set $V\subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $V$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}$. If $1\in V$, then $(f|_A)^{-1}(V)=[0,1]\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$, which is open relative to $A$. Otherwise if $1\notin V$, then $(f|_A)^{-1}(V)=\varnothing$, which is also an open relative to $A$.